# No package metadata was found for ros2cli

Tags: ubuntu, ros-humble

I installed Ros2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04.
When I launch the command ros2 I get the following error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2", line 33, in 
> sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.18.8', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
>
> File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
> for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/**init**.py", line 969, in distribution
> return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/**init**.py", line 548, in from_name
> raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
>
> importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for ros2cli

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You seem to be missing `ros2cli`.

Comment: For more help please edit your question to include what packages you've installed and how. As well as how you've setup your system.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the `PYTHONPATH` hasn't been set right.  For example, perhaps you explicitly set the `PYTHONPATH` in a non-additive way after running the `setup.bash` for ROS.